# jquery return true or false according custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind following code in custom function and return true if field has value and false if field is empty. Validating with only one variable, it was easy. But when validating two array I think it can be possible only custom function. I think code becomes unnecessarily lengthy as well because of lack of custom function. Please guide me.

```
$(document).on('click', '.subadd', function(){

    //I want to bind this code in function 
    var sid = [];
        $('input[name="sid[]"]').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).addClass('border1red');
            return false;
        };
        if($(this).val()){
            $(this).removeClass('border1red');
            sid.push(this.value);
        }
    });

    var title = [];
        $('input[name="title[]"]').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).addClass('border1red');
            return false;
        };
        if($(this).val()){
            $(this).removeClass('border1red');
            title.push(this.value);
        }
    });
 //function

 //if function return true

    if(sid.length && title.length){
        $('table#menutable tr:last').after("<tr>.....</tr>");
    };
});
```

Comment: You should share your html as well to make a working snippet. :)

Comment: Note returning `false` inside `each()` just stops the iteration of the objects in the jQuery collection, you are not actually returning a value to some outer variable / process.

Comment: Not really clear what is expected here. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can shorten your `each` loop.

```
if(!$(this).val()){
    $(this).addClass('border1red');
    return false;
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('border1red');
    title.push(this.value);
}
```

You can also make a function for that, with the selector and the array as parameters.

```
$.validate = function(selector, array) {
    $(selector).each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).addClass('border1red');
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('border1red');
            array.push(this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, the main section of the code would look like this:

```
var sid = [];
var title = [];
$.validate('input[name="sid[]"]', sid);
$.validate('input[name="title[]"]', title);
if(sid.length && title.length){
    $('table#menutable tr:last').after("<tr>.....</tr>");
};
```

Comment: @SystemGlitch, Thanks, works like a charm, but one problem where to apply AND operator, field is being added even if one input is empty.

Comment: @AnandHmt You can use two different arrays if you need. I updated the answer accordingly.